# How to invoke/run a Python script using a web URL?

Tags: python, web, url

I have a Python script that pulls data from a 3 rd party API. Currently this Pyhton script is automated on server side.

There are few instances where I have to toggle the script manually for new data updates. For the manual toggle I have to login to the server each time and run it from command line. Is there a way where I can create web url or something similar and just run that URL to make that script run from the browser address bar.

Comment: letting random people from the internet to be able to trigger something on your server doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Ofcourse the URL is going to have authentication in order to run from a browser. I already have few for PHP scripts have never done such for Python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach you could take is to use Flask, which is a minimal web framework. Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
from flask import Flask
from your_script import your_func

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/run')
def run_command():
    your_func()
    return 'Executed your function!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, port=8080)
```

If you run this code you'd get a web server running on port 8080 that executes your function when you access the url. Here's a [tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) in the Flask documentation to get you started.

Comment: This is super easy to setup just tested it locally and worked like a charm. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is by using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application).

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    # your code here
    return 'Hello, World!'
```